# What's the name of the battle theme used in Big Order?

Tags: music, big-order

I was watching [Big Order](http://myanimelist.net/anime/31904/Big_Order_TV) recently, and when I looked it up I could easily find the op, but I couldn't find that really awesome battle theme. It comes on IIRC once or twice per episode, and usually at the climax of the episode.

So, does anyone know its name?

I'm pretty sure it's in all of the episodes, but for a specific example, take the latest episode (ep 6). It's in most of the underwater scene, from around minute 20.

Comment: Could you maybe include a time stamp + the episode number?

Comment: @Dimitrimx sure, give me a minute. Kissanime seems to be down atm, so I'll use gogoanime or something

Comment: Whenever you have them [edit the info](http://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/32350/edit) into your question for the others too see as well :)

Comment: Umm, I don't think the official OST is available yet, so I'm not sure if it's answerable as for now.

Comment: [OST 1](http://vgmdb.net/album/58176) out July 29; [OST 2](http://vgmdb.net/album/58177) out Sept 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HS7fh_QD6sw#t=33m40s starting 33:40

It's called "决着！"

Comment: Note: 決着 is pronounced "Kecchaku" and means something along the lines of "conclusion".

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the name -.-, but I think this is the song:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dfQSLCUVSxs